# Rendering Problems in "Navigation Drawer Activity" - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

**Motivation:**

I am doing project and making an app in which after login I need to switch to Navigation Drawer Activity. But whenever I was adding a Navigation Drawer in my project the activity_navigation was always showing a rendering problem.

**Problem:**

After many hours I tried to make a new project, and then added only "Navigation Drawer Activity" the problem was still there in Rendering.

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

This is what i am getting by creating a new project having a simple "Navigation Drawer Activity".

This Rendering Problem only exists in **main_navigation.xml** and not in *fragment_navigation.xml* and *fragment_navigation_drawer.xml*

**Check List:**

Please note that
- Android Support Repository 
- Android Support Library
ALL are added.

**Help:**

There are many solutions available on siteS, blogs and even stackoverflow saying to change the build.graddle file and so on. I tried many solutions but couldn't find a satisfactory one. Please Help me in that regard.

Comment: For receiving good answers, please, be more specific. Any attached source or screenshot of what you have done will be highly appreciated and will help to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have more emphasized my problem and aided with a screenshot. Please Help

Comment: I found that for temporary purpose you may set `layout_`width` and `layout_height` as absolute for `Navigation Drawer`. for example `400px` or more or less. Also, it happen sometimes when `layout` becomes complicated or something. If you can run the app I don't think it is necessary. It happened many times for some types of layouts.

Comment: I changed the values to "layout_width" as 240dp and "layout_height" as 400dp in **main_navigation.xml** from text view. But not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem with Android Studio 1.2 and I've tried a lot of things but any of them works

For me the solution was to use the **Canary Channel** and update Android Studio to 1.3.

Now  I have this version and it works perfect but this is not and stable version

[image]

My build.grade is in this way

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidtest.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

This is the problem with Android Studio 1.2

[image]

and the same code with Android 1.3 is this

[image]